# Prolog singleton variables is shown

Tags: prolog

I have an error in my Prolog code:

```
member(X,[X|T]).
member(X,[H|T]):-
    member(X,T),!.
```

The code works and shows a correct results but I can't get the reason why that error is shown ?

Comment: No, your code does not work. There is a built-in `member/2` which is used. Thus, rename it. Your code is incorrect for `memberM(X,[1,2,3])`: only two solutions instead of the expected 3.

Comment: Get rid of `!` and mark singletons as `_`.

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning. *Singleton* variable means you have a variable that appears once in the clause and, therefore, appears to serve no purpose. As @false said, use `_` instead, *i.e.*, `member(X, [X|_]).` and `member(X, [_|T]) :- ...`.

Comment: @lurker: It's an error, too: `No permission to redefine imported_procedure lists:member/2`

Comment: @false yes, indeed, that's an error. The title of his question cited only the "singleton variables" which is what I focused on, but the redefinition is a bigger issue. To the OP, I'll correct my comment... use `_` instead and use a different name for your `member/2` predicate, *e.g.*, `member_of_list(X, [X|_]).` and `member_of_list(X, [_|T]) :- ...`.